# Kivy APK invalid signature unable to upload on google play

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, google-play, kivy

Environment:

- Python 3.6
- OS: XUbuntu 18.04
- Using [Kivy](https://kivy.org/) and [KivyMD](https://gitlab.com/kivymd/KivyMD)
- Building the release apk with buildozer

I have used buildozer to create a debug.apk for my app which runs without a problem on my android phone. Then I followed the tutorial [here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Creating-a-Release-APK) to create a release apk. Everything worked giving me a release-optimized.apk file.

I then went on google play console to upload my app and I got an error:

```
Upload Failed
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR (Jar signer CERT.RSA): JAR signature META-INF/CERT.SF indicates the APK is signed using APK Signature Scheme v2 but no such signature was found. Signature stripped
```

How can I resolve this issue? Are there any existing commands which I should run? Thanks in advance! ([Issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6611) on Kivy github)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously, I signed my KivyMD application with a third party apk signer. And it uploaded without any problems.
I built my application with the code below.

```
buildozer android release
```

And I signed and aligned my application with APK Signer Tool 1.8.5.

You can download APK Signer Tool 1.8.5 [from here](https://shatter-box.com/knowledgebase/android-apk-signing-tool-apk-signer/)  and learn how to use it.

Comment: Thanks I will check it out later! If it works I will accept this answer. So you only ran the command above without exporting any variables, creating keystores or zipaligning anything?

Comment: You are my hero!